# CodeIgniter url not working for new class

Tags: codeigniter

I uploaded CodeIgniter in my server, and the basic page works fine. 
Then I added home.php file in application/controllers folder with class Hello and function one, and tried to open the link url/index.php/Hello/one but I get the codeIgniter error that the page isn't found. What can I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your issue you should rename the Hello class to Home then go to URL/index.php/home/one

I recommend that you read up on the controller documentation:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

> A Controller is simply a class file that is named in a way that can be
>   associated with a URI.
>
> Consider this URI: example.com/index.php/blog/
>
> In the above example, CodeIgniter would attempt to find a controller
>   named blog.php and load it.
>
> When a controller's name matches the first segment of a URI, it will
>   be loaded.